# making ios 6 app compatible with ios 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, backwards-compatibility

I am developing an app in Xcode 4.5 targeting iOS 6 version. I want to make that app backward compatible for iOS 5 and all the iOS 5 versions. How can i do this? My app is complete and it is targeting right now iOS 6 only.

Comment: Also make sure to check your warnings for possible future deprecation problems.  This can prevent future compatibility rework.

Comment: Muhammad, you need to accept some answers in order to get a better reputation on this site. If you found any answer that answered your question or helped you, accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `xcode`, Press `Command + comma (,)` for `preferences` then select the `Download` tab and install the simulator which you want to test with. check the following image for more help

[image]

change project target like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the Deployment Target to 5.0, it might have been selected as 6.0.

Or from the top select 'iPhone 5.0 Simulator' or 'iPad 5.0 Simulator' or 'iPhone 5.1 Simulator' or 'iPad 5.1 Simulator' etc.

If None of the above works, then go to Xcode at the top, Go to Preferences (Or press Command + Comma) buttons and it will open up preferences.

Go to Downloads and Go to Documentation, Check and Install the simulators as per your need.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Answer (score 1):

First download all simulators.

Then select project name from left navigation bar, and then under "Build Settings" select "iOS Deployment Target" as iOS "4.3", so that, you will able to run your app in lower version 5.0.

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Comment: It's worth noting that he will have to convert his Storyboards to XIB files in order to make this compatible with 4.3. Storyboards are only supported in 5.0+

Answer (score 0):

I had a IOS app and when I changed the framework to be 5.0 weird bugs started popping up.  I have also found that I cannot install a IOS 6.1 app onto a IOS 5.0 ipad.  I can install a 5.0 version and then update it though.

The bugs seemed to revole aorund MYSQL, I have re-tested and everything is fine now, but i'm not sure what I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do I change the info.plist file from ios5 to ios6 so that I can run ios6 apps you could use ifile todo that.
Warning:if you get on cydia to install an app it could remove your unthethered jailbreak because it thinks youre running on ios6